# Get random element from attributes in an object

Tags: python, object, random, attributes

I have an object which got 16 double attributes and I want to pick one of them randomly so I create a method which create a random number between 0-15, but this method is not really what I want I think it's a pretty dirty method if you guys got another cleanest method

```
class Currencies(object):
    EURToUSD = 0.0
    EURToJPY = 0.0
    EURToBTC = 0.0
    USDToEUR = 0.0
    USDToBTC = 0.0
    USDToJPY = 0.0
    BTCToEUR = 0.0
    BTCToJPY = 0.0
    BTCToUSD = 0.0
    JPYToEUR = 0.0
    JPYToUSD = 0.0
    JPYToBTC = 0.0
    EURToEUR = 0.0
    JPYToJPY = 0.0
    USDToUSD = 0.0
    BTCToBTC = 0.0


    def __init__ (self):
        try:
            rates = urllib2.urlopen("http://fx.priceonomics.com/v1/rates/")
        except urllib2.URLError as e:
            return e.reasonx
        res = json.load(rates)
        self.EURToEUR = 1.000000
        self.USDToUSD = 1.000000
        self.JPYToJPY = 1.000000
        self.BTCToBTC = 1.000000
        self.EURToUSD = res['EUR_USD']
        self.EURToJPY = res['EUR_JPY']
        self.EURToBTC = res['EUR_BTC']
        self.USDToEUR = res['USD_EUR']
        self.USDToBTC = res['USD_BTC']
        self.USDToJPY = res['USD_JPY']
        self.BTCToEUR = res['BTC_EUR']
        self.BTCToJPY = res['BTC_JPY']
        self.BTCToUSD = res['BTC_USD']
        self.JPYToEUR = res['JPY_EUR']
        self.JPYToUSD = res['JPY_USD']
        self.JPYToBTC = res['JPY_BTC']

    def getRandomRate():
        randomNumber = randint(0,15)
        if(randomNumber == 1):
            return EURToUSD = 0.0
        if(...)
```

Comment: Your question's a bit vague; it would be nice to see some code. But anyway, you could build a list or tuple of the attributes and pass it to `random.choice()`.

Comment: Rather than storing all those conversion rates as separate attributes consider putting them into some kind of collection, eg a `namedtuple`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just select a random attribute from the [`vars(self)` dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars), filtering on names that match a pattern:

```
def getRandomRate(self):
    return random.choice([v for attr, v in vars(self).items()
                          if len(attr) == 8 and attr[3:5] == 'To'])
```

This picks a random value from all attributes whose name is 8 characters long and contain the word `To` in the middle.

A short demo using your class:

```
>>> import random
>>> c = Currencies()
>>> vars(c)
{'EURToBTC': u'0.0108027', 'BTCToJPY': u'12816.8350063', 'JPYToJPY': 1.0, 'USDToBTC': u'0.0094131', 'JPYToBTC': u'0.0000702', 'BTCToUSD': u'125.2057142', 'USDToUSD': 1.0, 'USDToJPY': u'116.1736146', 'EURToEUR': 1.0, 'JPYToUSD': u'0.0084464', 'BTCToEUR': u'92.3549138', 'USDToEUR': u'0.8820255', 'BTCToBTC': 1.0, 'JPYToEUR': u'0.0065705', 'EURToUSD': u'1.2338648', 'EURToJPY': u'126.4193644'}
>>> [v for attr, v in vars(c).items() if len(attr) == 8 and attr[3:5] == 'To']
[u'0.0108027', u'12816.8350063', 1.0, u'0.0094131', u'0.0000702', u'125.2057142', 1.0, u'116.1736146', 1.0, u'0.0084464', u'92.3549138', u'0.8820255', 1.0, u'0.0065705', u'1.2338648', u'126.4193644']
>>> random.choice([v for attr, v in vars(c).items() if len(attr) == 8 and attr[3:5] == 'To'])
u'0.0108027'
```

So the list comprehension extracted the 16 values for each of the conversion rates, and `random.choice()` then picks one of those rates at random.

Comment: I don't really understand your solution, if you can explain it a little bit more

Comment: @mel: `vars()` gives you a dictionary of your attributes; including `'EURToEUR'`, `'EURToUSD'`, etc. The keys are the attribute names, the values the attribute values. The code selects all those values, then picks one of them at random.

Comment: thanks but what about if len(attr) == 8 and attr[3:5] == 'To']

Comment: @mel: that's testing the string length (`'EURToEUR'` is 8 characters) and if the middle 2 characters from that string are `'To'`.